# how to cumulatively combine arrays from previous rows into one aggregate array? (Snowflake/SQL)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Imagine I have a table with two columns, a date DATE and an array of strings ITEMS.

I'd like to create a column ITEMS_AGG which contains an aggregate of all the arrays from previous rows, i.e. something like:

```
DATE   ITEMS      ITEMS_AGG
1      a, b       a, b
2      a, c       a, b, c
3      b, c       a, b, c
4.     a, d       a, b, c, d
5.     a, b, e    a, b, c, d, e
```

etc.

Answer (score 5):

Cummulative array_agg with distinct defined as **[JavaScript UDTF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/javascript/udf-javascript-tabular-functions.html)**.

Sample data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test(grp TEXT, date INT, ITEMS ARRAY)
AS
     SELECT  'X',1,  ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('a', 'b')       
UNION SELECT 'X',2,  ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('a', 'c')       
UNION SELECT 'X',3,  ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('b', 'c')       
UNION SELECT 'X',4,  ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('a', 'd')       
UNION SELECT 'X',5,  ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('a', 'b', 'e')
UNION SELECT 'Y',1,  ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('z')
UNION SELECT 'Y',2,  ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('y','x')
UNION SELECT 'Y',3,  ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('y');
```

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aggregate (TS ARRAY)
RETURNS table (output variant)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
STRICT
IMMUTABLE
AS '
{
  initialize: function(argumentInfo, context) {
        this.result = [];
    },
  processRow: function (row, rowWriter, context) {
       this.result = [...new Set(this.result.concat(row.TS))];          
       rowWriter.writeRow({OUTPUT: this.result.sort()});           
   }
 }
 ';
```

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM test,  TABLE(aggregate(ITEMS) OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY date))
ORDER BY grp, date;
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well not exactly what you seems to want, you can aggregate with double-ups with a recursive cte, as there is no ARRAY_CAT(DISTINCT) with this SQL:

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT column1 as date, split(column2, ',') as items FROM VALUES
    (1, 'a,b'),
    (2, 'a,c'),
    (3, 'b,c'),
    (4, 'a,d'),
    (5, 'a,b,e')
), rec AS (
    WITH RECURSIVE r_cte AS (
        SELECT date as date, items
        FROM data
        WHERE date = 1
        
        UNION ALL
        
        SELECT r.date+1 as r_date, array_cat(r.items, d.items) as items
        FROM r_cte r
        JOIN data d 
            ON r.date + 1 = d.date
    )
    SELECT * from r_cte
)
SELECT *
FROM rec;
```

| DATE | ITEMS |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [ "a", "b" ] |
| 2 | [ "a", "b", "a", "c" ] |
| 3 | [ "a", "b", "a", "c", "b", "c" ] |
| 4 | [ "a", "b", "a", "c", "b", "c", "a", "d" ] |
| 5 | [ "a", "b", "a", "c", "b", "c", "a", "d", "a", "b", "e" ] |

but really you should use Lukasz solution.

Comment: Actually, this looks good, and you may append a call to ARRAY_DISTINCT in your last SELECT line (I suspect it was not available 2 years ago). Remove the space from 'b, c' (small typo).

Comment: cheers for the white space bug, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but if you're stopping by, we can use a `lateral join` with `array_union_agg`

```
with cte (grp, dt, items) as

(select 'x', 1, ['a', 'b'] union all   
 select 'x', 2, ['a', 'c'] union all        
 select 'x', 3, ['b', 'c'] union all        
 select 'x', 4, ['a', 'd'] union all        
 select 'x', 5, ['a', 'b', 'e'] union all 
 select 'y', 1, ['z'] union all 
 select 'y', 2, ['y','x'] union all 
 select 'y', 3, ['y'])


select *
from cte a, lateral(select array_union_agg(b.items) as items_agg 
                     from cte b 
                     where a.grp=b.grp and b.dt<=a.dt) t2
order by a.grp, a.dt
```