# Concat rollup values

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with a column of dates.

```
emp_id,some_date
1,2002-11-23
1,2006-06-09
1,2009-05-05
1,2013-06-06
2,1978-07-05
2,1980-04-15
2,1984-08-31
```

I need my output to look like this

```
1 2002-11-23
1 2002-11-23,2006-06-09
1 2002-11-23,2006-06-09,2009-05-05
1 2002-11-23,2006-06-09,2009-05-05,2013-06-09
2 1978-07-05
2 1978-07-05,2,1980-04-15
2 1978-07-05,2,1980-04-15,984-08-31
```

the "rollup" should occur during an active period when the last value of some_date is in the period for example 2002-11-23,2006-06-09 would be the row returned when some_date is between  2006-06-09 and 009-05-04

Comment: It looks like you are searching for cummulative LISTAGG or recursive CTE. I have written an equivalent of **[the cummulative ARRAY_AGG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70864833/how-to-cumulatively-combine-arrays-from-previous-rows-into-one-aggregate-array)** in the past(with duplicate removal), which could be addapted with `ARRAY_TO_STRING(arr, ',')`

Answer (score 2):

You can `array_agg` it by emp_id and then slice it later by utilizing `dense_rank()`

```
with cte (emp_id, emp_date) as

(select 1,'2002-11-23' union all
 select 1,'2006-06-09' union all
 select 1,'2009-05-05' union all
 select 1,'2013-06-06' union all
 select 2,'1978-07-05' union all
 select 2,'1980-04-15' union all
 select 2,'1984-08-31')

select *,array_slice(array_agg(distinct emp_date) within group (order by emp_date) over (partition by emp_id),
                     0,
                     dense_rank() over (partition by emp_id order by emp_date)) as emp_date_array
from cte
order by emp_id;
```

Comment:  Interesting approach

Comment: Let me throw this into the mix.  Some of the emp_dates are null.

Comment: @SmokeMIfYouGotM Consider updating your sample data and expected output