# Array_Agg does not support Window Frame in Snowflake - how to achieve?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to run:

```sql
select arrayagg(o_clerk) 
  within group (order by o_orderkey desc) 
  OVER (PARTITION BY o_orderkey order by o_orderkey 
     ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS RESULT
from sample_data
```

But Snowflake returns the error `Sliding window frame unsupported for function ARRAYAGG`. If I try to accumulate all without a sliding window, I get the error `Cumulative window frame unsupported for function ARRAY_AGG`.

How can I achieve this?

Sample data:

```sql
create or replace table sample_data as (
    with data as (
        select 1 a, [1,3,2,4,7,8,10] b
        union all select 2, [1,3,2,4,7,8,10]
    )

    select 'Ord'||a o_orderkey, 'c'||value o_clerk, index
    from data, table(flatten(b))
)
;
```

[image]

Desired result:

[image]

([source](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D53r0000BySd2JCQS/migrate-from-big-query-to-snowflake-as-per-the-documentation-arrayagg-does-not-support-window-framehow-to-achieve-a-big-query-arrayagg-implementation-in-snowflake), for a BigQuery migration)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @Felipe Hoffa here's my solution posted initially in:

https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D73r000006upCECAY/detail?fromEmail=1&s1oid=00Di0000000hZh2&s1nid=0DB3100000001Fq&s1uid=0050Z000009Xcck&s1ext=0&emkind=chatterCommentNotification&emtm=1669252526852

```html
select o_orderkey, 
    array_compact([
        lag(o_clerk, 3) over(partition by o_orderkey order by index)
        , lag(o_clerk, 2) over(partition by o_orderkey order by index)
        , lag(o_clerk, 1) over(partition by o_orderkey order by index)
        , o_clerk
    ])
from sample_data
```

[image]

Comment: I love it, no join needed, and minimal memory needs

Answer (score 2):

Using the `ARRAY_AGG` and `ARRAY_SLICE`. Inspired by [Rajat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74185869/5070879)

```
SELECT *
   ,IFF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY o_orderkey ORDER BY INDEX) <= 4, 0, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY o_orderkey ORDER BY INDEX)-4) AS start_index
   ,IFF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY o_orderkey ORDER BY INDEX) <= 4, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY o_orderkey ORDER BY INDEX),4) AS num_elem

   ,ARRAY_SLICE(
         ARRAY_AGG(o_clerk) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY INDEX)
                            OVER(PARTITION BY o_orderkey)
         ,start_index
         ,start_index + num_elem) 
FROM sample_data
ORDER BY O_ORDERKEY, INDEX;
```

Output:

[image]

---

The start_index and num_elem computation could be further simplified/generalized to emulate window sliding frame  `ROWS BETWEEN PRECEDING prec AND FOLLOWING foll`.

```
SELECT *
   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY o_orderkey ORDER BY INDEX) AS rn
   ,3 AS prec
   ,0 AS foll
   ,ARRAY_SLICE(
         ARRAY_AGG(o_clerk) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY INDEX) 
                            OVER(PARTITION BY o_orderkey)
         ,IFF(rn <= prec+1, 0, rn-(prec+1))
         ,IFF(rn <= prec+1, 0, rn-(prec+1)) + IFF(rn <= prec+1, rn+foll,prec+1+foll)
   ) 
FROM sample_data
ORDER BY O_ORDERKEY, INDEX;
```

Displaying each argument of ARRAY_SLICE for debug:

[image]

Comment: Nice! Get a huge array for every row, and only then slice it later.

Answer (score 0):

Since we can't get these results with `ARRAY_AGG()`, we can through a self join.

First we give each row a row number, and then we choose everything between its number and +3:

```sql
with numbered as (
    select o_orderkey, o_clerk, index
    from sample_data
), crossed as (
    select a.o_orderkey, a.index ai, b.index bi, b.o_clerk
    from numbered a
    join numbered b
    on a.o_orderkey = b.o_orderkey
    and a.index between b.index and b.index+3
)

select o_orderkey, array_agg(o_clerk) within group (order by bi)
from crossed
group by o_orderkey, ai
order by o_orderkey, max(bi)
```

Note that to the original question I had to add a `index` field - so we could have an unambiguous sorting order within rows.

[image]